# File history in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, comparison, history, tortoise-svn

In SourceSafe I could simply see the history of all the changes for any given file.
And then I could pick any two versions from that list and compare.

How can I do it in Subversion via Tortoise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tortoise has a [show log](http://tortoisesvn.net/easy_to_use) option.  Just right click on a file and choose it from the tortoise menu.  you can then select two versions and see the differences.